# Zend_Translate vs Zend_Navigation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-navigation, zend-translate

I build a internet application with multi languages. I setup everything well, it work when I call as an example site.com/fr/ I get all in france or site.com/en/ all in english.

I try to get these languages also in my zend_navigation url's like the example above.

for the navigation config I use the application.ini

I hope someone can explain this part or give me an example how I put the 'lang' parameter in the url build by zend_navigation trought the application.ini

With kind regards,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected language in the url of the navigation dont start the uri by '/foo/' but like 'foo/'

example application.ini

```
resources.navigation.pages.popular.label = nav_popular //zend_translate
resources.navigation.pages.popular.title = nav_popular //zend_translate
resources.navigation.pages.popular.uri = popular/
resources.navigation.pages.popular.resource = "popular"
```